# How to compare between two dates in power bi query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a column named status compared between the End date of the task and each month in the year to return 1 for true, 0 for false

i have used this:

`Status =  IF ([EndDate].[Date] <= [Month].[Date] , 1, 0)`

Date Formatting for [EndDate] and [Month]: March 2001 (MMMM yyyy)

The problem : if End Date = May 2019 and Month = May 2019 its returned 0 ,but  its should returned 1

**Actual Result**
[image]

**Expected Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct logic/syntax, is the date you are using just visually formatted as MMMM yyyy, is the actual date in the dd/mm/yyyy format? as you may be trying to compare the following

[EndDate].[Date] = 01/05/2001 to  [Month].[Date] 25/05/2001

What you can do is just pull out the month and year for example

MONTH([EndDate].[Date]) and YEAR([EndDate].[Date]) and MONTH([Month].[Date]) and YEAR( [Month].[Date])

So it would be IF(YEAR([EndDate].[Date]) = YEAR( [Month].[Date]) && MONTH([EndDate].[Date]) = MONTH([Month].[Date]), 1, 0)

Comment: sorry, I forget to mention if the year is in 2019, 2020 and more, for example now it returns 0 because Jan 2020 is less than May 2019 which is not correct.

Comment: have you tired using <= in the Year, that may help